# When adding urlpatterns in Django, why is views.index called instead of views.index()?

Tags: python, django, url

I was wondering, in the url.py-files, why are parentheses not used when calling methods from the view.py-files?

For example, why does the following code not have a parenthesis at the end of views.index?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Because you're not calling the function. You're passing it as an argument to the `url` function (which will store it for calling it when appropriate).